# Pivottable Filter less than 0

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table, filtering

I have a little problem. I want to filter a pivottable field with a value less than or equal zero. I would like to use a vba code for filtering the table.

The filter just functions for values equal zero. For values less than zero I have to set the filter manually again.

The field i would like to filter is called ("Bestand nach " & Chr(10) & "Vorratsentnahme")

Here you can see what my code looks like in this part. What I'm doing wrong. Thanks in advance.

```
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields( _
        "Bestand nach " & Chr(10) & "Vorratsentnahme").ClearAllFilters
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields( _
        "Bestand nach " & Chr(10) & "Vorratsentnahme").PivotFilters.Add2 Type:= _
        xlCaptionIsLessThanOrEqualTo, Value1:=0
```

Comment: Have you tried `xlValueIsLessThan` in place of `xlCaptionIsLessThanOrEqualTo` ?

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```vb
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1).PivotFields( _
                  "Bestand nach" & Chr(10) & "Vorratsentnahme")
    .ClearAllFilters
    .PivotFilters.Add xlCaptionIsLessThanOrEqualTo, Value1:=0
End With
```